What happens physically at the white hole - black hole transition in Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates?
Imagine you are an observer that starts on the timelike past $i^-$ of a maximally extended black hole spacetime and immediately shoots along a null ray hovering on the past horizon $\mathcal{H}^-$ of the white hole. I suppose since you are at the horizon of the white hole, you should have your rockets on full thrust inwards (that is: In the negative $r$ direction), since the white hole is trying to push you out. Now, if you do that you'll eventually reach the bifurcation point, after which the white whole becomes a black hole. I have no idea what happens to you then. The few ideas that come to mind are:

Following the null ray along the horizon, it would seem like you suddenly appear hovering on the future horizon of the parallel universe. So it would seem once you cross the wormhole (which you are just barely doing since you are moving over a null ray). The thing that feels weird is how you transition from thrusting inwards to avoid being ejected from a white hole to thrusting outwards to avoid being sucked by a black hole.

You keep thrusting inwards so you immediately fall full speed into the black hole. I don't see how this would be represented on a spacetime diagram, but it does sound physically like the thing that should happen.


On a related note, is there any intuition at all about this transition? What happens to an observer that is just hanging out along a timelike geodesic inside the white hole as they cross the bifurcation point? Or less dramatic, how does the transition look for an observer hanging out along a timelike geodesic on the outside region. They constantly see stuff coming from the white hole, so I guess they can't know about the transition, but if they go in the direction from which they are receiving white hole signals, they will find a black hole... It is all very confusing.
Comment: I understand this is not a physical solution since astrophysical black holes come from the collapse of a star so they are not eternal. But still, eternal black holes are a valid solution to GR so I'd like to know how an observer in that solution would perceive it.

white hole is trying to push you out No. White hole has attractive gravity, same as black hole.

@P.C.Spaniel “They constantly see stuff coming from the white hole” - The Kruskal white hole is a vacuum solution that does not radiate. No stuff is coming from it. As a perturbation, you can imagine a photon moving from inside out. To become visible outside, the photon would have to be emitted at the past eternity, because it takes an infinite coordinate time for anything to cross the anti-horizon.

@P.C.Spaniel “an observer that starts on the timelike past $i^-$“ - This is impossible. The diagram is compactified, so $i^-$ is an infinity, not an event, from which one can start. Hence $i^-$ is a point excluded from the diagram. Playing with infinities is a dangerous game.

@P.C.Spaniel “transition from thrusting inwards to avoid being ejected from a white hole to thrusting outwards to avoid being sucked by a black hole” - This is incorrect. You cannot thrust inside a white hole or at the anti-horizon, but only outside trying to remain close to the anti-horizon. Once you cross the black hole horizon, you are inside the black hole and cannot thrust to avoid being sucked in - you are already in. Thus your #2 is represented by an (almost) straight line just outside and (almost) parallel to the anti-horizon continuing just inside the horizon.

There are a few errors in the question that make answering this question difficult.

… an observer that starts on the timelike past $\mathcal{i}^{−}$
of a maximally extended black hole spacetime …

Timelike past infinity is not a point. Its appearance as a point on Penrose–Carter diagram is an artifact of conformal compactification procedure. It might be useful to think of $\mathcal{i}^{−}$ here as a codimension one space, modeled as a 3D hyperbolic space with a singular point corresponding to the past of white/black hole. Without  knowledge of the structure of $\mathcal{i}^{−}$ one should be able to at least specify past asymptotic state of an observer by providing their asymptotic trajectory as their proper time goes to $-\infty$.
So, it is unclear, which asymptotic past trajectory did OP have in mind?

…  and immediately shoots along a null ray hovering on the past horizon $\mathcal{H}^{−}$ of the white hole …

First, what does “immediately” even mean when talking about past infinity? It is not a moment of time. Second, trajectories of observers are always timelike, they cannot “shoot along null rays”, no matter how powerful the rocket ship we place them in.

… since the white hole is trying to push you out …

White hole is not trying to push anything out. White hole has exactly the same attractive gravity as black hole.  This is most easily seen through Newtonian limit: time reversal of solutions of equations of motion for Newtonian gravity gives us again solutions of Newtonian gravity with the same attractive character and same masses. The whole distinction between white/black hole does not make sense for observers staying outside and in the absence of accretion/radiation. From relativistic perspective, the impossibility of entering the white hole region has the same geometric origin as impossibility of an observer  catching up to a photon that has been emitted from said observer's position with, say, 1 second headstart.

… if you do that you'll eventually reach the bifurcation point, …

Observer starting at timelike past infinity cannot reach this bifurcation point. Only observers  from inside the white hole region, i.e. originating on past singularity, can reach bifurcation point. Penrose–Carter diagram shows that quite clearly: causal past of bifurcation point is precisely the white hole region.
Consider the following setup: an observer falls freely and radially towards the white/black hole, so that at a time $t=0$ (Schwarzschild time coordinate) they are at a distance $r=100 r_\text{S}$ and have velocity $0.01 c$ directed toward black hole (numbers are  arbitrarily chosen). Imagine that observer sends a photon precisely at $t=0$ toward the black hole. Both observer and that  photon would eventually cross black hole event horizon. Though both of these occurrences would  correspond to $t=+\infty$ by Schwarzschild time coordinate, these are distinct events, they have different Kruskal-Szekeres (KS) coordinates and they would correspond to different points on KS diagram. Let us  denote these events as $A$, the crossing of horizon by observer, and $B_0$, crossing of horizon by a photon emitted by observer at $t=0$. Obviously, $T_A>T_{B_0}$ (where $T$ is KS timelike coordinate). Now, imagine that this observer emits photons toward the black hole not just at one moment but all the time, so instead of a single event horizon crossing point there are points $B_t$ for all values of $t$, and a bifurcation point emerges as a limit of points $B_t$ as $t\to - \infty$, (i.e. $T_{B_t}\to 0$ and $X_{B_t}\to 0$ as $t\to -\infty$). So, from outside spacetime perspective bifurcation point can only emerge as a limit.
On the other hand, observers created by the white hole singularity inside the white hole region have no trouble reaching the bifurcation point. For example, worldline $X=0$, $T\in (-1,1)$, $\theta,\phi=\mathrm{const}$ is a timelike geodesic starting and ending at singularities and passing through bifurcation point.
And last, keep in mind we have been calling it a bifurcation point while we are keeping angular coordinates fixed and considering only radial motion. But actually it is a bifurcation surface, an $S^2$ sphere of radius $r_\text{S}$.

Can you please elaborate or point out a flaw in my reasoning? Attraction vs. repulsion is about acceleration. Inability to enter the white hole is about velocity. Moon is attracted to Earth and yet it is not falling into it. This is a simple illustration of the difference between acceleration (which always points towards Earth) and velocity (which is approximately orthogonal to acceleration).

place an object with a zero velocity anywhere near the antihorizon How do you define near? For example, is the point with Schwarzschild coordinates $r_0=(1+10^{-30}) r_S$, $t_0=-10^{1500} r_S/c$ near the antihorizon? If we calculate geodesic that has $dr/d\tau=0$ ar $(t_0,r_0)$ then $dr/d\tau$ would become negative immediately, So for example, when $t=(-10^{1500}+1)r_S/c$ the radial coordinate would be smaller than $r_0$. So, attractive and if you wish to call it that, "falling to the antihorizon".

I see what you are saying. Thank you for the effort to explain, I appreciate it. So, no matter how close to the antihorizon, by the time the object falls down, the white hole already has become the black hole, so the object hits the horizon instead of the antihorizon. This is evident on the Penrose diagram by the fact that the antihorizon is not in the future lightcone of any external event. Thanks again for your help!
