Would a rotating charged black hole have a magnetic field? (Unrelated to the accretion disc)
In this question, the general consensus is that a charged black hole does have an associated electric field, due to the charges that have at some point gone inside (since their retarded potentials existed before the black hole did).
Now, if the black hole is also rotating, then the inner charge would also be rotating, producing a current loop that one could a priori assimilate to that of a circular wire carrying a current. And therefore, it should have a magnetic field.
Does the argument presented in the answer to the electric field question apply here? After all, while the charges existed before the black hole and therefore their contribution also did, they weren't necessarily forming a current that would have an associated magnetic field.

It depends on who measures it. Since we are working in general relativity, different observers may disagree on the value of the magnetic field, and sometimes even on whether it is nonvanishing. Even if the black hole is not rotating, a moving observer may measure a nonvanishing magnetic field. What is the observer you're interested in?

This question was already answered at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/757551/24093 but the tags "kerr-metric" and "reissner-nordstrom-metric" are offtopic, the tag should be "kerr-newman-metric".

“the charges that have at some point gone inside” - Nothing goes inside ever, as observed from outside.

@safesphere wrote: "Nothing goes inside ever, as observed from outside" - that's true due to time dilation, but there is also stuff that was already inside long before the star started to collapse to a black hole.

Wikipedia has formulas for the electric and magnetic potentials and fields of a charged rotating black hole.

@safesphere - You should google the difference between astrophysical and eternal black holes, since it's nonsence to assume the collapsing stars are all hollow.

@safesphere - Those statements are all false, even in the context of eternal black holes and even more in the context of astrophysical black holes. For eternal black holes the inner radius measured with stationary rulers like in Droste coordinates is imaginary and measured with free falling rulers like in Raindrop coordinates is 2GM/c², but never 0 except for photons (Null oordinates). For astrophysical black holes the horizon hasn't even formed yet from the outside perspective and we have a frozen star with interior which only converges to, but never actually reaches infinite time dilation.

@safesphere - My email is the same as my website, but if we discuss that subject via email in the end both of us will claim to have won the discussion, so we should do it in a proper thread here where the upvotes and downvotes will decide who's right. We already discussed everything in the comments of other threads without reaching a concensus, but since they were all moved to chat no one can prove who's who and what's what. If there was a real question about that and both of us could write a proper answer we just have to count the votes.

@Yukterez I don't care for popularity contests judged by a flock of parrots. My best hope in a debate is to be proven wrong, only then I learn something new and I am happy to admit it. Here I argued that a Kruskal white hole is repulsive and A.V.S. helped me see my error: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/832889/833205#comment1887575_833205 - Another example is our recent debate about a tape measure. I think you may be correct there, but I am still pondering. We don't have to debate if instead of sharpening your understanding all you need is upvotes.

@safesphere - Sure, but in a closed email discussion we have the risk that if you or I learn nothing from it nobody will learn something from it, while in an open Q&A the risk of wasted time is less since at least someone else might learn something from it.
